# The most optimized way to copy and duplicate elements of an array into new one

Tags: javascript, arrays, time-complexity

What's the most optimized way to copy and duplicate an array into a new one, so `arr1 = [1,2]` becomes `arr2 = [1,2,1,2]`?

I can do this:

```
for(let a of arr1){
    arr2.push(a)
}
for(let a of arr1){
    arr2.push(a)
}
```

Is there a more optimized way to do it with a more efficient time complexity?

Comment: It's going to vary by browser JS engine - but there's probably a _generally_ correct answer. Your best bet is to do your own testing since jsperf.com is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just benchmarked your loops vs. `const arr2 = [...arr1, ...arr1]` with 100k items in an array in Chrome. The results:

```
For loops: 291 ops/s
Ellipsis:  513 ops/s
```

So `[...arr1, ...arr1]` was faster by 43%. You can go ahead and test further in other browsers and/or different array size.

Comment: Let's not forget the humble [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) which beats both push and spread hands down in large arrays, but ends up being much slower on smaller arrays!

Comment: @chazsolo you are right, I tested `const arr2 = arr1.concat(arr1)` and it was actually 85% faster than `[...arr1, ...arr1]`!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.concat()` works in 30% of the time taken by `...Array` which takes about 66% of the time taken by `Array.push()`

The test below uses an array with 10,000 elements and logs the total times taken to perform each method 100,000 times. It takes about 30s to complete the tests on my machine. I get results like:

```
wait for it ...
push: 14853
spread: 9332
concat: 3063
```

```js
const n = 100000
const a = [...Array(n/10).keys()]

console.log("wait for it ...")
const concatTest = () => {
  let b

  const s = Date.now() // go
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    b = a.concat(a)
  }
  console.log('concat:', Date.now() - s) // time

}

const spreadTest = () => {
  let c

  const t = Date.now() // go
  for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    c = [...a, ...a]
  }
  console.log('spread:', Date.now() - t) // time

  concatTest()
}
const pushTest = () => {
  let d

  const u = Date.now() // go
  for (let k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    d = []
    for (let x of a) {
      d.push(x)
    }
    for (let x of a) {
      d.push(x)
    }
  }
  console.log('push:', Date.now() - u) // time

  spreadTest()
}
pushTest()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your time complexity here is O(N) (while you do 2N operations, we ignore the constant 2), where N is the size of `arr`. A more optimized time-complexity would mean making your code run in sublinear time, which isn't possible here as you need to look at each number in `arr1` at least once to be able to push it into your new array. You can do some tweaks to improve the runtime of your code overall (as other answers have shown), but that will not improve the time complexity of your solution (as they are two different things).

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will do:

```js
const arr2 = [...arr1, ...arr1]
```

OR

```js
 const arr2 = arr1.concat(arr1)
```